# QUERY_TOO_COMPLICATED pulling a specific record over REST API

Tags: soql, rest-api, api

We are pulling an account for a customer and after around 25 seconds it times out with an error.

`GET https://xyz.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/Account/001xxx`

```
[
    {
        "message": "Query too complex.",
        "errorCode": "QUERY_TOO_COMPLICATED"
    }
]
```

What's so complex about this? Could the customer have some triggers attached?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Triggers are not firing when a record is queried, but formula fields are recalculated. This error is normally happening, if the SOQL query to get record information, exceeds the character limit of 20K.

I can make an assumption, that the `Account` object has a big number of custom fields (more than 250) and some of them can be pretty complicated formula fields.

Edit your `GET` request to include only fields, which you need to get:

```
/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/Account/001xxx​?fields=AccountNumber,BillingPostalCode
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct! Thanks so much